# Is it bad practice to put UIViewControllers in other UIViewControllers?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, xib, subview

I know there is the common practice in iOS development of having one UIViewController presented on the screen whose view is loaded from a XIB which will contain all the UIView subclasses in it.

While I was working on a pretty complex widget for an app, I decided to make the widget subclass a UIViewController instead of a UIView. This was because I thought a UIViewController was essentially a UIView with some helper methods around it. Then I could create a XIB for it (I know UIViews can have their own XIBs too), load the views it contains, place ITS view in the presented parent VC's view, and lay it out.

This works fine so far, but I'm wondering if this is bad practice and if I should just subclass a UIView instead and give it a normal NSObject controller. I am seeing some problems with this and I was wondering if anybody could address concerns I have with this approach?

EDIT NOTE: The widget VC does NOT relate to the VC view it is in and is reusable on ANY screen. So the answer is not subclassing the widget VC with the parent VC. The widget is INSIDE the parent VC, but it is NOT a parent VC.

EDIT NOTE 2: I am NOT using Storyboard. Only Autolayout, XIBs, and ARC.

Why can't we have VC's in VC's?

1) Can VC's be simply dropped into ANOTHER VC's XIB and be loaded easily as a subview?

2) I read here: [When to use a UIView vs. a UIViewController on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690852/when-to-use-a-uiview-vs-a-uiviewcontroller-on-the-iphone)

The top answer explains how the VC controls rotation of the screen and laying out the subviews again, so if you add another VC, then the system will automatically think that THAT is the main VC and will attempt to rotate it instead, causing problems.  Is this true?  Or is he just talking about if you somehow got into a state where 2 VC's were "presented"?  I wasn't sure if his answer applied to VC views that were SUBVIEWS of other VC views.

3) In general is this good practice?  It certainly seemed more reasonable as it made loading the subview VC's view much easier.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's absolutely fine. The answer to your problem is `ContainerView`.

> Container View defines a region within a view controller's view subgraph that can include a child view controller. Create an embed segue from the container view to the child view controller in the storyboard.

Comment: ContainerView doesn't seem to be anywhere except in Storyboards. Do they NEED to be in a ContainerView or can we just manually set the view of the child VC as a subview and assign the child VC as a child of the parent VC and that's it?

Comment: Yes, Apple does that too. You can read this article which is quite comprehensive https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right. Yes, it's good to make a view controller for what you needed. But you shouldn't just add it's view to the parent view, you should also add the view controller as a child view controller of the first view.
 You can add many views controllers as child view controllers of a view controller.

You can learn more about this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6).

Comment: @lespommes He's not suggesting subclassing.  You can add a view controller, regardless of class, as a child vc to as many other vc's as you want.  Likewise, you can add as many child vc's to a vc as you'd like as well.  You also can do this programmatically since you're not using storyboard.

Comment: Completely misread that answer. Whoops. Dunno how I read subclass instead of child. Thanks! Comment deleted.