# change view controller programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIViewController` which have a button and I have created two view controllers in `StoryBoard` and connect it to Cocoa classes. I want to change `UIViewController` to one of the two view controllers depends on some conditions.

I have tried:

```
// 1
BOOL isLoggedIn=TRUE;
NSString *storyboardId = isLoggedIn ? @"FirstViewController" : @"SecondViewController";
self.view = [self.view.inputViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardId]; 

// 2
[self.view addSubview:FirstViewController];
```

I'll appreciate your prompt reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your sub view controller from `Main.storyboard` and from identity inspector on the right menu change `StoryBoardID` to **someID**

Then, add this code to the button action method:

```
ViewController *NVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someID"];
[self presentViewController:NVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: If your first UIViewController is in the storyboard as well, you can create a segue between the two, name the segue, then call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` from code. That way you can see/modify the transitions from your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not understand the difference between `UIView` and `UIViewController`. Here is the post you should go from SO: [When to use a UIView vs. a UIViewController on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690852/when-to-use-a-uiview-vs-a-uiviewcontroller-on-the-iphone)

Comment: I have tried creating UIView before, but did not work with previous code. Then, how to present UIView after button is pressed?

Comment: Your question is too general that it's so hard to let us help you out in this community. You better learn a little bit more before asking question?

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply. I have found similar questions, I'll try it.

Comment: Solved without using UIView!